# Cell containing 2-D varying dimension matrices

Tags: matlab

I have a big 2D matrix of, say, 1000 by 10. I am trying to split that matrix into multiple 2D matrices. They can be 10 by 10, 5 by 10 or 23 by 10. The column size does not change and I am splitting them based on the number in the first column. (In my true case, I do it for the first two columns.) In other words, I'm putting the rows with same id tag, which is the first column value of the vector.

I am trying to achieve this through for loop. And I think it is best to put them into a 'cell array' because cell array allows user to have data in different dimension and different types. So, I want a cell (1-by-varying-N?) where N is the number of matrices split and there are N 2D matrices of varying sizes.

Here my questions are

1. In this case, should I think the cell as 3-dimension?
2. How can I initialize a cell with varying dimension?
3. Given that I have 2D matrix in n-by-m, how can I insert the matrix into a cell?

There are not very many references with varying cell dimension. Any tip / answer would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example to show you how you can out arrays into cells:

```
A=cell(2,1); % create a 2x1 cell array
A{1}=ones(3); % put a 3x3 matrix into the first cell
A{2}=rand(5); % put a 5x5 array into the second cell
A{3}=zeros(2); % grow the cell array to 3x1 and put a 2x2 matrix in the third cell
A % see what A looks like
```

So you can grow cell arrays, for example in a `for` loop, e.g.:

```
A=cell(5,1);    
for i=1:5
    A{i}= ...
end
```

Comment: It appears that I had misunderstood about Cell. Your example presented directly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

1. In this case a 3D cell array is not advisable. Just use a 1D cell array and put the 2D arrays inside of it.
2. You can initialize a cell array using `myCell = cell(44,1)`
3. You can populate the cell using `myCell{4} = data(1:23, :)`

For example, you could write the following bit of code:

```
% Create some arbitrary data:
data = (1:1000)'*(1:10);
blockSize = 23;

% Create a cell array from scratch:
myCell2 = cell(ceil(1000/blockSize),1);

for ind = 1:ceil(1000/blockSize)
    myCell2{ind} = data((ind-1)*blockSize +1 : min(ind*blockSize, end),:);
end
```

But I would recommend avoiding the for loop and using the function `mat2cell(...)` instead like this:

```
% Create some arbitrary data:
data = (1:1000)'*(1:10);

blockSize = 23;

% Break it up with mat2cell:
myCell = mat2cell(data, [ones(44,1)*23; 11], 10)

% And just for fun, do a calcuation:
cellfun(@norm, myCell)
```

Comment: Steve, thank you very much for your kind response. I learned a lot from your example code. I only picked the other answer because, in my case, 'blockSize' varies for every data. So, I think I need to keep using Cell data type. Much appreciated though!

Comment: @ElectroJunkie Sure thing. You will still find that removing the for loop will increase performance for very large matrix sizes or very small block sizes. You can do all sizes changing as `mySizesY = [10, 50, 24, 102, 500, 20, 12, 278, 4]; mySizesX = [ 5 5]; mat2cell(data, mySizesY, mySizesX)`